# getting the value of the previous elements in other template in xslt

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Source:

```
<Data>
    <AB>
        <choice>Disclose</choice>
        <image>
            <img alt="No Image" xlink:href="abcd:202-11587" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="Image" />
        </image>
        <link>abcd</link>
    </AB>
    <AB>
        <choice>All</choice>
        <image>
            <img alt="No Image" xlink:href="abcd:202-2202" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:title="Image" />
        </image>
        <link>all</link>
    </AB>       
</Data>
```

XSLT

```
    <xsl:template match="Data">
         <xsl:for-each select="AB">
         <xsl:variable name="temp" select="choice"/>
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="$temp='Disclose'">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="image/node()"/>                  
                </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
         </xsl:for-each>

    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="simple:image/xhtml:img">
    <!-- I want to get the the name of the "choice" here-->

    <!-- some other process-->
    <!-- how to access the value of the <choice> element of that section-->
    <!-- how to access <link> element of that section-->
  </xsl:template>
```

Can any one help how to do it.

Comment: Could you possibly edit your question to make it a bit more clear exactly what is being asked? It is not immediately obvious that the comments within your XSLT sample is actually the question here. Showing some expected output would also help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, as this may just be an oversight with your code sample, you have specified namespaces in your matching template

```
<xsl:template match="simple:image/xhtml:img">
```

However, there are no references to the "simple" namespace in your sample XML, so in this case it should just be the following

```
<xsl:template match="image/xhtml:img">
```

But in answer to you question, to get the **choice** element, because you currently posisioned on the **img** element, you can search back up the hierarchy, like so

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../choice" />
```

The '..' represents the parent element. So, you are going back up to the **AB** element, and getting its child **choice** element.

And similarly for the **link** element

```
<xsl:value-of select="../../link" />
```

Note, it doesn't have to be xsl:value-of here, if there were multiple **link** elements, you could use **xsl:apply-templates**

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="../../link" />
```

And, if you required only **link** elements that occurred after the parent **image** element, you could do something like this

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="../following-sibling::link" />
```